How to write a character thrown into a new world and a training period to get accustomed to this new world?
I'm writing a story about a Victorian Shakespearean actress who is thrown into a new world. She was told that she was invited to an elite acting school in Paris with the promise of a scholarship, but that means that she's leaving her sick grandmother. But it turns out its a way to transfer her into this different realm where everything is much more different. How can I write a way to introduce her to this new world while also explaining it to my readers? Because she has to go through a training sequence as well to get accustomed to the new language and many other studies so she can get accepted into the new school? I know her motivation is to become famous and she's offered a spot in this really elite school that hasn't even heard of. How can I make it seem realistic and understandable for her to accept the deal even if it means that she's leaving her family?

Describe what happens and how your character copes with it. If you don't know what happens and how she feels, make it up. That's your job as an author: inventing stories. We cannot do that for you. If you need inspiration, read a bunch of portal fantasy to see how this is done. TVTropes has a list of works as has Wikipedia.

We follow the Three-Act Structure, aka 3AS.
As with most stories; you introduce your character in her "Normal World."
This means she is caring for grandma, and presumably she loves grandma, but (complication) she is also unhappy that there are no opportunities for her in her "Normal World." Her grandmother asks her about stuff like this, and grandma knows she is holding back our hero, even though our hero is not blaming her.
Then (3AS) we have an "inciting incident". Something new happens, our hero finds an advertisement,for example. Seemingly by accident, perhaps even magically -- there is a gust of wind and a sheet of paper literally hits her in the face. (Maybe not an accident, we later find, it was made to do that.)
She reads it, it sounds made for her. She brings it home, and grandma sees it.
"Somebody is going to be very lucky, don't you think, Grandma?"
Then Grandma thinks about it for a few days, but makes a decision. She lies. She tells her granddaughter she has been feeling much better. She is making a turn. And in fact, granddaughter, you should apply for this.
Granddaughter defers; but grandma insists. She will be fine, and an opportunity like this comes along once in a lifetime. Go! Go!
Granddaughter decides to apply. That is the end of Act I.
She accepts the deal, even though she is leaving her family, at her family's insistence, because they love her and are willing to sacrifice for her, because they know how much it would mean to her, because she's been a faithful caregiver and they don't want her to miss a once in a lifetime opportunity.
You follow the 3AS. In Act II, Granddaughter has left her Normal World, and immediately, things get worse. She has challenges to overcome. She doesn't know what is going on.
In general, the basics of story is that your Hero needs to get beaten up (physically or metaphorically) again, and again, and worse, and worse -- but keeps getting back up and trying. The best thing you can do to make your story interesting is to give your hero trouble to overcome, setbacks, confusion about what is going on.
But your hero keeps on trying. And keeps on failing, but makes progress, learns as they go, until happy ending -- They finally prevail, and are better people for having been tested by fire.
And then perhaps she returns to her "Normal World", with more knowledge and power to actually put her grandmother into the good health her grandmother was feigning, to get her granddaughter to go in the first place. A happy ending.
